# Como realizar una consulta MYSQL con PHP y que no me arroje datos dobles en cada fila

Tags: php, html, mysql, array, pdo

Me estoy conectando por medio de PDO a una base de datos MYSQL y hago una consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
$consulta = $conexion->query("SELECT nombre, grado, escuela FROM usuario WHERE pais = '{$_POST['_pais']}'");
$c_tabla = $consulta->fetchAll();
```

El problema es que por cada fila me arroja lo siguiente:

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => Nombre1
            [0] => Nombre1
            [grado] => Grdao1
            [1] => Grdao1
            [escuela] => Escuela1
            [2] =>Escuela1
        )
```

Y al momento de recorrerlo con un foreach los datos salen dobles, mi pregunta es ¿Como puedo hacer que solo me solo me entregue un tipo de arreglo, ya sea referencial o con un indice numérico, pero no los dos?

Answer (score 0):

Se pueden pasar las constantes PDO::FETCH_* (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Para devolver un array asociativo (arreglo diferencial):

```php
$sth->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Para devolver un array con índices:

```php
$result = $sth->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```